# RequireJS Optimizer - Only combine require lib and main.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, requirejs-optimizer

My build step for my RequireJS project is taking too long (about 14s) to combine all my modules and export to a single file. This means developing while watching my files has become extremely tedious. I'm using the node module to compile and I've already tried all the tips on the [RequireJS Optimizations](http://requirejs.org/docs/optimization.html#turbo) page (including setting `optimize` to `none`), and haven't seen any significant difference in compile time. At this point, all I want to do is combine the require lib, the config, and the `main.js` starting file, so that all the other modules can be loaded through network requests.

I've thought about switching to Browserify or Webpack, but I haven't found any real proof that they will be faster solutions.

**EDIT: My build config is below:**

```
{
    baseUrl: 'js/',

    name: 'requireLib',

    paths:  {...paths},

    shim: {...shims},

    optimize: 'none'
}
```

Comment: So lets see your require config.

Comment: FYI: I had very positive experience with Browserify and Gulp.

Comment: Added my build config. Not much to look at, but thats kinda the point.